# Android - Can I store the positions of multiple imageview and then retrieve it later?

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

Is there a way for me to store the positions of my imageviews somewhere?

What I am trying to implement:
these imageviews can be dragged and dropped onto different position on the relativelayout, the positions are then stored after being moved.
everytime the user enters this activity, the previously stored imageviews will be displayed in the same positions as last moved.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible, you can store the positions in a preferences or store in database

Answer (score 0):

You can save the position into preferences or database and retrieve them later.

If you want to save them only for that time when user is into your app then you can use static Arraylist or anything to save position for that time when your user is into your app (this data will be erased whenever your app will be stopped so use database or `SharedPreferences` for later use).

Cheers
-Aman